# Reactive Form Management In Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, algorithm

I don't know how I could manage my form in my case. Imagine a form of 7 initial values :

- Name
- Company
- Email
- Address
- Product (repeatable)
- Serial Number (repeatable)
- Return Shipping Instructions

There is a button that creates a new instance of the Product and Serial Number input field component (in case there are more products). This would mean that I would need to create another component to make a nested form. The issue I am having is that I don't know how I could manage that.

I currently log my values like so :

```
    console.log(this.parentForm.controls.name.value);
    console.log(this.parentForm.controls.company.value);
    console.log(this.parentForm.controls.email.value);
    console.log(this.parentForm.controls.address.value);
    console.log(this.parentForm.controls.returnInstructions.value);
```

But I am still trying to figure out how I could store my Product and SN values (as well as having a possibility to delete them). I was thinking about storing them in an array of objects that would be sent to the parent component (the one with the main form). The array would look like that : {Object1: product1, SN1, Object2: product2, SN2...} but event that, I don't know how to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for a form array. The validation below is just for example.

```js
  get products(): FormArray {
    return this.fooForm.get('products') as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fooForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      company: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],     
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      address: '',
      products: this.fb.array([this.buildProduct()])
    });
  }

  buildProduct(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      serialNumber: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

And then remove like so:

```js
  removeProduct(index: number): void {
    this.products.removeAt(index);
  }
```

Add product like so:

```js
  addProduct(): void {
    this.products.push(this.buildProduct());
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot I even asked the question. I did some research and this is exactly what I ended up doing !!